# MySQL - Checking to see if a patient has had another appointment booked after a completed appointment, broken down by day

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I am attempting to determine patient reappointments. I would like to get a list of appointments, grouped by patient and date, of any appointments they had that day, and what appointments they may have had after that particular day. If they did have another appointment after that day, that is considered a reappointment.

The appointment table is as follows:

ApptID: Primary key

PatientID: ID of the patient

ScheduleDate: Time the appointment took place.

ApptStatus: 3 for complete, 4 for scheduled. This may be extraneous because I want to search for one completed appointment occuring after another completed appointment as well as any scheduled appointments, but I left it in here for clarity.

This is my query so far:

```
SELECT
    a.PatientID,
    a.ScheduleDate AS CompletedAppointment,
    MIN(futureappt.ScheduleDate) AS NextAppointment,
    CASE
        WHEN MIN(futureappt.ScheduleDate) IS NULL THEN 0
        ELSE 1
    END AS CountPatsReappointed,
    1 AS CountPatsSeen
FROM
    `appointments` a
    LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT
                fa.PatientID
              , fa.ScheduleDate AS ScheduleDate
            FROM
                `appointments` fa
            WHERE
                fa.ScheduleDate > NOW()
            GROUP BY
                fa.PatientID
              , fa.ScheduleDate
        )
        futureappt
        ON
            futureappt.PatientID = a.PatientID
WHERE
    a.ApptStatus                      = 3
GROUP BY
    a.PatientID
  , a.ScheduleDate
  , futureappt.ScheduleDate
```

The data, schema, and my attempt at this are [in this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e8fc0b/6).

Actual result (using this Patient ID as an example)

```
ApptID  PatID   CompletedApp           Next   Reapp    PatSeen
269584    3144    2018-05-25T10:30:00Z    (null)    0    1
269826    3144    2018-05-29T14:45:00Z    (null)    0    1
```

Expected result. Note how the next appointment shows up, thus counting as a reappointment:

```
ApptID  PatID   CompletedApp           Next   Reapp    PatSeen
269584    3144    2018-05-25T10:30:00Z    2018-05-29T14:45:00Z    1    1
269826    3144    2018-05-29T14:45:00Z    (null)    0    1
```

How can the query be rewritten to achieve the above results?

Comment: It's great that you provided a fiddle, but could we focus a little more closely on the 'M' of 'MCVE'?

Comment: You compare with ScheduleDate > NOW(). Why would you expect that a date in the past turns up?

Comment: Since I do not understand what you want to achieve exactly, I cannot answer properly. However I think this might help you in the right direction: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e8fc0b/8/0  (Great thing, a fiddle, we can fiddle around ;) )

Comment: The objective of ScheduleDate > NOW() is to return any future appointments after today. What I would like to achieve, though, is a column listing a patient's appointment and another column listing the next appointment they had after that day. Hope this clarifies things a little!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A window function would work well here, but they are only supported in MySQL v8.0.

Instead, have a look at the query below, [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e8fc0b/14).
Note joining the second appointments table on `fa.ScheduleDate > a.ScheduleDate`
and you don't need to group by `fa.ScheduleDate`

```
SELECT
    a.PatientID,
    a.ScheduleDate AS CompletedAppointment,
    MIN(futureappt.ScheduleDate) AS NextAppointment,
    CASE
        WHEN MIN(futureappt.ScheduleDate) IS NULL THEN 0
        ELSE 1
    END AS CountPatsReappointed,
    1 AS CountPatsSeen
FROM `appointments` a
LEFT JOIN `appointments` futureappt
    ON futureappt.PatientID = a.PatientID and futureappt.ScheduleDate>a.ScheduleDate
WHERE
    a.ApptStatus                      = 3
GROUP BY
    a.PatientID
  , a.ScheduleDate
```